# How can I load a HTML page end then make a Request in Razor

Tags: c#, razor

I'm new to working with Razor, and I have a doubt.

I have a page that makes a request to the database to populate a table, but that request takes too long so the HTML waits for the request to be loaded to render in the web browser.

This is the request that takes too long

> ```
> <section id="studentList" class="form-group">
>     <div class="table-responsive">
>         @{Html.RenderAction("Search", new { situation = 3, unity = "", course = "", ra = "", name = "", page = 1 });
>         }
>     </div>
> </section>
> ```

and in my cshtml page and I would like to render de HTML First end then do this request to not be in a blank page waiting to be loaded.

If someone could help me.

I appreciate your attention and I'm really grateful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

A Html.Render(-X) will always be server side constructed, therefor the browser will need to wait before your result is completed because there is no data to transmit. The partial view needs to be completed before anything will be ready to be sent.

Since Razor is still just "MVC" (for nitpicking: yeah I know, it isn't "MVC" I know this, it's a gross simplification, but for lack of a better way to explain this, just accept it "as is"). You can also use (like on a "normal" web page) javascript (or jQuery or whatever framework you want) to load content after document.Ready.

There are multiple ways to achieve this, I suggest you start by searching for "Razor Ajax" or "Razor partial refresh" or whatever.

Comment: Oh Thanks!

So razor works in a server side, that's why the HTML waits the whole request to be loaded.

Do you have any example how could i do it?

Thank you a lot!